# What is the covenant of Subh?

Tags: salat, covenant

According to a hadith, "[whoever prays the Subh then he is under the protection of Allah's covenant, so do not be treacherous with Allah in his covenant.](http://www.sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2#74)"

Evidence exists of many different covenants between God and mankind, each with their own terms and conditions: **What exactly is the nature of this particular covenant, and when was it covenanted?**

Answer (score 1):

- Haafiz Manaawi said:

  The interpretation (will come under the Protection of Allah) means in his protected or secretariat or guaranteed, so don't cause him damage, in muslim word (lest Allah should call you to account) and in at-Tirmidhi novel (so do not be treacherous with Allah).
- And ibn al-'Arabi said:

  This is an indication that the conservation non impossible for the person, But God will take his right from it. So it is telling about the occurrence of the penalty not for conservation from harm.
- **And potentially** protection be prayer  that lead to safety, Meaning Do not leave the morning prayer because leads to the failure of the Covenant which between you and your god.

**The bottom line,** there is warning in this hadith from exposure to harm those who prayed  in the group because he is under the Protection of Allah.
So who cause of harm to a person who is in the protection of God has offered himself for revenge.

**If a Muslim prayed Fajr in congregation, so he's under God's protection, it does not mean that there were no incidents with him, but the occurrence of the penalty for those who caused him harm**